# Cost for Maintaining the Build Farm

Tags: ros-groovy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

How much would it cost in terms of the build farm for not end-of-life-ing a particular distribution?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/191133/cost-for-maintaining-the-build-farm/) by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) on ROS Answers with karma: 10932 on 2014-08-24

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2014-08-25**:
The EOL announcement for Groovy was sent out today: http://lists.ros.org/pipermail/ros-release/2014-August/004511.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The cost of supporting a specific platform for a specific duration is very hard to estimate. There are three main types of costs. The most obvious cost is the direct hosting costs for servers and bandwidth. The type of cost is the man hours of administration and maintenance of the buildfarm and management of the distribution. And the final type of cost is the developer effort to maintain all released packages to avoid bit-rot.

Unfortunately the ability to measure the costs is correlated with the magnitude of the cost. The direct hosting costs are small compared to the cost of having a few people maintaining the distro. And that is a much smaller cost than the collective work required by all the maintainers.

Other factors to keep in mind are startup costs vs maintenance. There's a very large effort to kick off a new distro up front to fix all the issues which occur from changing dependencies upstream. There's also correlation between distros, sometimes changes can easily port between similar architectures, but sometimes they need architecture specific patches.

Also relating to extending support for EOL'd platforms. The cost goes up significantly as the upstream dependencies become EOL and no longer get updates and patches in parallel. (For example there's an issue with [arm_navigation_experimental in groovy](http://lists.ros.org/pipermail/ros-release/2014-August/004512.html) which only manifests on Quantal. To fix this will likely require a patch to work around the lack of updates upstream because Quantal is EOL.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2014-08-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) on 2014-08-28**:
Thanks for the thorough answer Tully. Is there a wiki page that specifies the sunsetting of the various distros?

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2014-08-28**:
The [Distributions wiki page](http://wiki.ros.org/Distributions) has the policy that we will support them while upstream targeted platforms are supported. And target_platforms are in [REP 3](http://www.ros.org/reps/rep-0003.html) Though for non-LTS releases of ROS we may need to add a caveat.

**Comment by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) on 2014-08-29**:
Thanks. I had seen that, but was looking for the dates. Really, what I'd like is something like this: [http://i.stack.imgur.com/ihPiQ.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ihPiQ.png)

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2014-08-29**:
If you take REP3 and correlate to the two supported distros, you can use that graphic.